# Load Angular CLI generated app via System.import in html-Head

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a similar issue to this one (accessing multiple components without app-root):

https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/building-wundergroundcom-drupal-angular-2-challenge-1-how-bootstrap

but I can´t find a way to load my CLI generated app this way:

```
<head>
...
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
...
 <script>
  System.import('app')
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
 </script>
</head>

<body>
 <comp1>
   loading...
 </comp1>
 <div>
   Static content rendered server side.
 </div>
 <comp2>
  loading...
 </comp2>
</body>
```

I don´t know how to access System and if it´s even possible with my CLI-managed Project, since i´m not able to access the deeper configuration. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: Angular-CLI generated project are not using System.JS but Webpack

Comment: Thank you! So what is the webpack way to achieve that?